# Cplex: Windows vs. Linux

Tags: cplex

I am running a bin packing problem variant with a Windows test environment and Linux production environment that are solved to a limited number of solutions instead of optimal (speed is important and good enough is fine).

When I run in Windows, it will find several solutions within 1 sec.  When it is run in Linux it will not find a second solution within 2 hrs.  Is there a way to make Cplex run similarly between the two environments?

Consistent behavior is more important than "fixing" the Linux run.

For clarification: I have exported the .lp file and run CPlex directly reading this.  I have turned off pre-solve (preind = 0) as well as turning off various cuts and fixing branching rules to attempt to reduce potential differences. This has been tested with 12.6.0, 12.6.3, and 12.8.0 and all exhibited the same behavior.  This has also been tested within and outside of the OPL environment.

Comment: Are the two machines otherwise similar in terms of hardware? Running on Windows vs Linux can be like running with different random seeds. It could be that your problem is susceptible to variability. If you export your model to .sav format you might try using the `runseeds` command in the interactive (new in CPLEX 12.7) to evaluate this.

Comment: Just in case , even with older versions with OPL you may measure random seed impact using a loop in the main block. See https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=2bbb5d8a-b968-44ff-b4e7-4f9089f4b694

Comment: I have tried this on 4 different Windows computers and 3 different Linux (similar company issued specifications), plus one instance of running Docker containers on the same machine.  The random seeds doesn't seem to be the core problem, but may be worth looking at more closely as I lock in the branching strategies.

Comment: Verified that random seed is not the issue with identical default and performed a set of runs with different identical choices across platforms.

Comment: There is a related thread on the IBM developerWorks forum [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=0a6a90e3-d629-4cd4-b936-06d4dacffc36) and a technote [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21399979).

Comment: If you like, you can share your model file and parameter settings with me at `rkersh at ibm dot us dot com`. If we can reproduce the issue we may be able to provide better guidance.

Comment: Someone else from the company opened a service request with IBM over the same issue yesterday with a different model/system.  I am going to work with them and the service request team and will post any information we glean.

Thank you for the offer rkersh

Comment: The problem isn't solved, but 3 distinct steps have gotten us close enough:
1) Fix the number of threads. Performance is varying widely with the number of threads
2) Explicit variable naming. The default names are different on different platforms.  Noticing mathematically identical .lps with different default names behaved differently.
3) No pre-solve and fixed branching strategy.
There are still minor differences on occasion, but not affecting the solution or greatly changing solve times.

Comment: @M.A.Colv, you may want to answer your question so that it's clear that we don't need to come back to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consistent behavior can only be expected if the computing environments are **exactly** the same. In order to improve your chances for consistent behavior, make sure that environments are as similar as possible:

- use the same number of threads
- use the same amount of memory available
- use the same limits
- use the same hardware
- be careful with wallclock time limits (they introduce variability even within the same machine)
- if you have any wallclock time limits then make sure that the CPLEX job is the only job running (otherwise it may get preempted randomly and depending on the OS)